# using lang.hitch for xmlhttprequest

Tags: ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I did not catch the way to use lang.hitch in XMLHttpRequest. Is there any idea for that?

```js
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange(lang.hitch(this,function()
            {
                if (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200)
                {
                var t=xml.response;
                this.method();
                }
            }
            ));  
xml.open('GET',someURL, false);
xml.send();
```

Comment: what's the matter here ? could you post your probleme , error !

Comment: This code should work. Just post the error or your real question.

Answer (score 0):

In dojo there is class concept. We can define methods in the class. Then the codes architecture will be clear. For the event response part, the operation scope will be limited in the response function and lose the class scenario.

These days I found a solution not depend on dojo lang.hitch,the way is:
In the main scenario set this to a variable by: 
        var instance=this;
In the asynch method(response), if call the method in the main scenario by :
   instance.SomeMethod();

```
   sendXMLRequest: function () {
     var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xml.responseType = "json";
     xml.open('GET', url, true);
     var instance = this;
     xml.onload = function (e) {
          if (this.status == 200 || this.status == 304) {
           instance.SomeMethod();
                  } 
            } 
     xml.send();
   },
SomeMethod:function(){
   //do something.
}
```